# Mongodb db.getCollection().save() not works in forEach cursor loop

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I met a problem with updating documents in mongoDB. What I need: loop through each document in collection, fix some issues in data and save document:

```
var isDateValueAsObject = function(date){
    return (date && date.value && isObject(date.value));
};

var checkPropAndUpdate = function(obj, prop){
    if(isDateValueAsObject(obj[prop])){
            if(obj[prop].value.value){
               obj[prop].value = obj[prop].value.value;
               return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
};

db.getCollection('trials').find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    if(doc.revisions && doc.revisions.length > 0){
        var updated = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < doc.revisions.length; i++){
            var rev = doc.revisions[i];
            updated = updated || checkPropAndUpdate(rev, "lastchangedDate");
            updated = updated || checkPropAndUpdate(rev, "startDate");
            updated = updated || checkPropAndUpdate(rev, "completionDate");
            updated = updated || checkPropAndUpdate(rev, "firstreceivedDate");
            updated = updated || checkPropAndUpdate(rev, "primaryCompletionDate");
            updated = updated || checkPropAndUpdate(rev, "verificationDate");
        }
        if(updated){
            db.getCollection('trials').save(doc);
            print("updating: "+doc.trialId);
        }
    }
});
```

By some reason db.getCollection('trials').save(doc); does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Plenty of things are wrong here. MongoDB is "smart", being that if you ask to update a property with the same value that already exists it will not do anything. Also `.save()` is the **wrong** way to do things. Look at atomic operators such as [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) to be used with [`.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) instead.

Comment: I didn't update property with same value. Script should fix issues with some documents:  obj[prop].value = obj[prop].value.value;

Comment: How does it fix the problem? I don't want the database to do useless work.

Comment: What is wrong with the save? Mongo [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/db.collection.save/) tells that if _id property exists it should update the document. The save part is called for documents I wanted to change so the logic is okay.

Comment: What is wrong is that it potentially overwrites changes made in another interaction before you call `.save()` after a process such as `.findOne()`. Basic race conditions. So understand that the `.update()` mentioned earlier is the better way to do things, since you are "touching" the database once, and also with only the changes you mean to incur.